# mysql table update by name with out affecting id

Tags: mysql

how can I use the command update in mysql to order a column by name instead of id.

```
update tb_rack set id = @counter := id order by name;
```

I tried other ways but only mess up my table.
thanks.

this is the table.

id,floor_id,room,name,units.

```
90, z1
56, c3
2, a1
45, a3
80, b5
1, a4
5, c5
```

this is what i want.

```
2,    a1
45,   a3
1,    a4
80,   b5
56,   c3
5,    c5
90,   z1
```

Comment: Maybe stupid, but WHY ?

Comment: because that will fix the order it is choose from the php drop down box. so far c5 is the last when z1 it is suppose to be.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa43d/1/0

Comment: @user2734395 how do you populate your php drop down box ?

Comment: i guess i have to fix it from php, i thought that was easy from msyql command.

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables are inherently unordered.  If you want the results to be in a particular order, then use the `order by` clause on a `select` statement:

```
select r.*
from tbl_rack r
order by name;
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "order a column by name instead of id".  That statement does not make sense for SQL tables and columns.

Comment: thanks. this what happens,  on browser the drop down box list Z1 as the first choice when A1 it is. when i do select * from table. A1 is the last one. when i do order by name only order what's display on screen. I wanted to change it permanent, so next time that i just do select * table, displays A1, and Z1 last.

Comment: @user2734395 . . . Just add the `order by` to your query.  You don't want to depend on the database returning results in a particular order.

Answer (score 1):

the answer "to do what you want" would be

```
SET @r=0;
UPDATE tb_rack set id= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY  name;
```

the good answer would be

you should never mind the order of your datas IN THE TABLE (you can't rely on that)

You should use `ORDER BY name` when *retrieving* datas, if you need an name ordering.

Comment: i think you were close with this command but it did not work because it finds duplicate PRIMARY KEY and changes the real id to a higher number.